# Windows 10 update screwed up grub-not getting any options to dual boot to Linux

Tags: dual-boot, bootloader

I was away from Linux for quite some time(around 3 months or so)...haven't even booted...but my grub menu was working fine...i believe during last 3 weeks or so some Windows 10 update happened and now i am not seeing any grub screen which can give me the option to boot into Linux. After boot - it straight away goes into Windows 10. 
Just wanted to tell I had Windows 10 only(not upgrade from Windows 7 or Window 8.1 to Windows 10).

I used to just try out this command:

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi
```

I forgot last time what i used in place of {bootmgr} etc...
Please help me try to recall and fix this issue.

I just need to create the live USB for Ubuntu Desktop 16.04 LTS and then try ubuntu and follow the steps after wards, right? Please let me know.

Update
If i follow the above question. I have some doubts about step # 2 and # 3

Determine the partition number of your main partition. GParted (which should

> already be installed, by default, on the live session) can help you
>   here. I'm going to assume in this answer that it's /dev/sda2, but make
>   sure you use the correct partition number for your system! Mount your
>   partition: sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt  #Replace sda2 with your
>   partition number

[image]
[image]

I have two hard drives and my entire Ubuntu is on second drive /dev/sdb. /dev/sdb also contains windows. /dev/sda is all windows.

So what should be the commands for me for:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt #Replace sda2 with your partition number
```

Comment: The first step of the accepted answer to the linked question is: “Boot from the live CD or live USB, in "Try Ubuntu" mode.” So yes, you need to create a live USB and follow the remaining steps.

Comment: @L.D.James - it worked...thanks a lot for all your help in chat.

Answer (score -1):

> Just wanted to tell I had Windows 10 only(not upgrade from Windows 7 or Window 8.1 to Windows 10).

This is happening to you because windows now use an upgrade new system, not only to upgrade from previous windows but from older windows 10 versions. In your case the windows 10 anniversay update was the reason. This when installed, it's like installing a new system from the scrach so no matter what solution you find, when a new windows 10 version came up this could happen to you again unless you use different hard drive for each system, each one with their on MBR.

Comment: That sounds like it's supposed to be an explanation of the problem but I don't see any solutions.

Comment: The solution is at the end of my comment, use two hard drives. And yes it's an explanation of the problem to avoid it in the future.

Comment: "How to avoid the issue" is not the same as "how to resolve the issue", so it doesn't qualify as an answer even though it sounds like a helpful comment. Sorry.

Comment: @DavidFoerster if it's a helpful comment, as I can't comment because I don't have 50 points yet, don't downvote my answer. I think it gives helpful information even if don't resolve the issue.

Comment: I understand that, but the Stack Exchange network sites are very strict on the distinction between answers providing solutions, and comments. Comments showed up as a origin of spam, and heavy discussions not fitting the Stack Exchange model – this is why some reputation is required for posting them, showing you got familiar with the site’s idea. This is not meant for annoying new users, but keeping the site’s quality high. (See [Why and how are some answers deleted?](/help/deleted-answers))

Comment: @DavidFoerster. Regarding my issue - if i am not wrong. I just need to create the live USB for Ubuntu Desktop 16.04 LTS and then try ubuntu and follow the steps after wards, right? Please let me know.

Comment: @Ashu: Could you please edit your question if you have a follow-up question? The comment section is not suitable or meant for new questions or extended discussion. Notify me [in chat](//chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room) if you want to draw my attention to the change. Thanks.