# Windows 10 has disabled the dual boot

Tags: dual-boot

Windows 10 has disabled the dual boot.  The system now boots directly to windows 10 without any chance to boot to Ubuntu.  I've been running 14.04 successfully for along time, but I needed to use windows so I used the dual boot to switch to it and now I can't get back to Ubuntu.

Update - 
Thanks for your replies.   The problem did happen after I installed the windows 10 anniversary update so that was probably the cause.  For some reason I don't understand it suddenly started working normally.  So I booted Ubuntu and ran the Boot-repair program from the dashboard which found some errors and updated to a newer level.   All is well now.

Comment: That's MS for you :(

Comment: Do you still have the Ubuntu install USB stick or DVD?

Comment: @MarkYisri If he doesn't have one already, he can make one easily enough using Rufus.

Comment: You may have been hit by the notorious Windows 10 "Anniversary Update". Can you still get to the GRUB menu by holding down the **LEFT SHIFT** key at boot time? If not, boot to the Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, get a gparted screenshot of /dev/sda, and edit your question to include the screenshot. I'll bet your Ubuntu partition is gone too. Cheers, Al

Comment: heynnema is correct... this is anniversary update..read about it on google..update deleted all the partitions of ubuntu... if u dont see linux disk from. Disk management..only solution is to dual boot again !

Comment: Fun fact is..when i manually installed win 10 anniversary update iso on my pc...my ubuntu was still there(reinstalled grub only). and people who did it online..bam! ubuntu gone!

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue with Windows 10.
Please refer [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/832824/windows-10-update-screwed-up-grub-not-getting-any-options-to-dual-boot-to-linux)

I referred to this [one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows) which is the golden source of information.

and for me, this command once you are booted again and again into Windows

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi
```

worked

Comment: -1 Unclear. If you're saying the solution is in the linked questions, then flag as duplicate. If you're saying the solution is running that `bcdedit` command, then why are you mentioning the other questions?

Comment: Because apart from the referenced solution it's this command "bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi" that worked for me.